# Automatic merge of objects referenced from another collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to store object called "Wsp" in one document and one of its properties called "Sit" in another. I read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/ so i created structure like this:

```
    public class Wsp{

       public ObjectId Id{get; set;}
       public Guid WspId{get; set;}

       public List<Sit> SitList{get; set;}

       public string Name {get; set;}
       public ......... {get; set;}  
       }

       public class Sit{
             public ObjectId Id {get; set;}
             public Guid WspId;             //Id of a parent Wsp object

             public ......... {get; set;}  
       }

       //disabling Wsp from saving SitList into document (only Name, WspID and other..)
       BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Wsp>(map =>
            {
              map.MapProperty(p => p.Name);
              map.MapProperty(p => p.WspId);
              ...
            });
```

Now I want to create `GetWsp(Guid wspId)` and `AddWsp(Wsp wsp)` which will automaticly map List of Sit to the Wsp. For example :

```
public Wsp GetFullWsp(Guid id)
    {
        var wsp = wspCollection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(w => w.WspId == id);
        //no code for List<Sit> !!
        //wsp will have List<Sit> automatic filled from "SitCollection" based on WspId
    }
```

How to configure such query? Can I use in some way `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` ?

Is this a good approach any other suggestions? I read about `MongoDBRef` but it is told that performance drops using it and performance is the most important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a sitCollection:

```
public Wsp GetFullWsp(Guid id)
{
    var wsp = wspCollection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(w => w.WspId == id);
    var sits = sitCollection.AsQueryable().Where(sit => sit.WspId == id);
    wsp.SitList = new List<Sit>(sits);
}
```

But, I think you may want to consider your model. I see 3 options:

1. Have a single collection of wsps and store the sit list as an embedded document array.
2. Add a collection of SitListDocument and store its Id in the wsp document.
3. Add a collection of sits (flat) and every one of them stores the wsp document id (which is close to what you currently have but without having a SitList in wsp)

I would go with the first, but it depends on your specific needs.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I DON'T want to do. I want SitList to be AUTOMATIC filled without the code you wrote. Because when I will be adding more properties in future i don't wan't to put changes in 10 methods but only in some sort of "mapping schema".
1. Embedded document means that everything is stored in one collection ? Bad idea for me because I want to manage separate collection for Sit's from console and have more sql table's like look.
2. Can you say more about this or provide some documentation ?
3. So how will I process Sit's from Wsp without having such property?

Comment: @rexilion well, you can't. That's why I explained the actual options you DO have. In the first option, you wouldn't have to map anything but it means that the list will be saved embedded in your wsp document.

Comment: it will be too big, far bigger then 16MB. I really would like to have nice separation between collections. Did you ever work with MongoDBRef ? Maybe this is solution for my problem?

Comment: @rexilion You would still need to combine the data from the 2 collections together yourself. There's no magic here. And in that case it's better to work with the documents Id. That would be my third option.